# Angular: Make custom HTTP Validator not display error message when validation request is in "pending"

Tags: angular, rest, validation, http

in an Angular dialog I am using for some input fields custom backend validation, that checks the existance of the typed-in value. If the value could not be found it displays an error message right under the field. 
However, it also displays an error message when the request to the backend is still in "PENDING". When the request is done and status code 200 is returned, the error message vanishes. I do not want the error message to be displayed though when the request is in pending, only when the request is done and an HTTP error is returned.

My custom Validator looks like this:

```
public articleExistsValidator(formControl: AbstractControl): Observable <ValidationErrors | null > {
return this.meterReplacementService.getArticle(this.clientName, formControl.value).pipe(
  map(
    article => {
      if (article) {
        this.ac_equipmentNumber = article.equipment.equipmentNumber;
        return null;
      }
    }),
  catchError ( err => {
    this.articleError = 'MeteringChangeProcessDlg.errorMsg.articleNotFound';
      return Observable.throw(err.statusText);
    }
  )
)
```

}

I implement this one normally through a FormGroupBuilder. and formControl tag in HTML.

This is the HTML code snippet from an own HTML component which is responsible for the error message.

```
  <div *ngIf="formControlDefined() && (!formControl.valid && formControl.touched)"
   class="inputLabel error-label">
{{errorMsg}}
```

So the problem is that the validator turns invalid once the request is started and in pending.

How can it be changed?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you post your html as well?

Comment: @user2216584 I added details, I cannot post my entire html unfortunately but it's more because of the custom validator

Comment: Does it work if you check against formControl.invalid && formControl.touched?

Comment: @leurer Unfortunately not because it does not display the error message no matter if the request is successful or not

Comment: seems like the problem is, that when a request is pending buth formControl.valid and formControl.invalid return false.